# How to say 2000 people attend X High School

Tags: spoken-language

I was wondering how I would say 2000 people go to (Name) High School in Japanese.  It might be easier to say 毎日、二千の生徒はX高校に通ういます。but it would like to know how to phrase it more like X高校は二千の生徒が（verb)。How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Ignoring any other issues, surely they don't all go to school *every* day? I'd hope they got Sundays off.

Answer (score 5):

The most common phrase to describe that would be:

> 「Ｘ高校{こうこう}の生徒数{せいとすう}は2,000人{にん}です。」

followed probably by:

> 「Ｘ高校には2,000人の生徒がいます。」

and a more formal way to say that would be:

> 「Ｘ高校には2,000名{めい}の生徒が在籍{ざいせき}しています。」

Your first sentence:

> 「毎日{まいにち}、二千の生徒はX高校に通{かよ}ういます。」

contains a couple of mistakes.

「二千の生徒」⇒「二千人の生徒」

「は」⇒「が」　← 「は」 is not an option.

「通ういます」⇒「通っています」

Make those corrections and you will have a fairly natural-sounding sentence.